# What are the use cases of Kotlin inline properties?

Tags: kotlin

As properties' *getter* or *setter* don't usually have function as argument nor [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) type, what would be the benefits / use case of using `inline` properties?

If the benefits would be to reduce cost related to method call, why not make all properties getter/setter inline by default?

[Kotlin Inline Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-properties-since-11)

Eg.

```
val foo: Foo
    inline get() = Foo()

var bar: Bar
    get() = ...
    inline set(v) { ... }
```

Comment: Inlining has a cost in terms of extra generated code, which in turn places pressure on the cache.

Comment: AFAIK inline is suited for higher-order functions, so that the generated code will look more like java, or in other words, it will generate a full method for your higher order function. I have never seen a property accessor being inlined like that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is inline properties [discussion](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/34):

> Example of reified type parameter:
>
> ```
> inline val <reified T : PsiElement> T.nextSiblingOfSameType: T?
>     get() = PsiTreeUtil.getNextSiblingOfType(this, T::class.java)
> ```
>
> Another use case is to hide some properties from the binary interface of a library. In Kotlin standard library, together with the `@InlineOnly` annotation this might make it possible in the future to exclude declarations of such properties from class files, reducing method count, this will mostly benefit Android with it's 64K method limit.