# Kotlin inlined extension property

Tags: kotlin, inline, kotlin-extension, jvm-bytecode

I know **inline** keyword means to avoid the call overhead calling a funtion. But I can't figure out what inline a extension property work for?

Let say we have two extension property named *foo* and another with is inlined named *bar*

```
val Any.foo : Long
    get() = Date().time

inline val Any.bar : Long
    get() = Date().time
```

Executing any of them, we gent the expected output, the current time.

The bytecode for this file is this below:

```java
public final class InlinedExtensionPropertyKt {

  public final static getFoo(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "$receiver"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 9 L1
    NEW java/util/Date
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/util/Date.<init> ()V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Date.getTime ()J
    LRETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  public final static getBar(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "$receiver"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 12 L1
    NEW java/util/Date
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/util/Date.<init> ()V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Date.getTime ()J
    LRETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE $i$f$getBar I L0 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  @Lkotlin/Metadata;(mv={1, 1, 7}, bv={1, 0, 2}, k=2, d1={"\u0000\u000e\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0009\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\u0008\u0005\"\u0016\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u0001*\u00020\u00028\u00c6\u0002\u00a2\u0006\u0006\u001a\u0004\u0008\u0003\u0010\u0004\"\u0015\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u0001*\u00020\u00028F\u00a2\u0006\u0006\u001a\u0004\u0008\u0006\u0010\u0004\u00a8\u0006\u0007"}, d2={"bar", "", "", "getBar", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)J", "foo", "getFoo", "test sources for module app"})
  // compiled from: InlinedExtensionPropertyKt.kt
}
```

We can see both are similar but differents only on these lines:

**foo** extract:

```
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

**bar** extract:

```
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE $i$f$getBar I L0 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

I really don't understand what is happennig here. 
Can someone point me to see what is the behaviour, or the equivalent in java, or some use for this?

**Edit**

Given the compiler will replace the content of inlined property, it may convenient to inline every extension property having not heavy operations ?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Kotlin's doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties),

> Note that, since extensions do not actually insert members into classes, there's no efficient way for an extension property to have a **[backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)**.

and [also](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-properties),

> The `inline` modifier can be used on accessors of properties that don't have a **backing field**.

As mentioned above, an *inline extension property* does not have a backing field. You may treat an extension property as a pair of static getter/setter, like this:

```
//In Kotlin
var Any.foo : Long
    get() = Date().time
    set(value) {
        //Cannot access field here since extension property cannot have backing field
        //Do something with `obj`
    }

//In Java
public static long getFoo(Object obj) {
    return new Date().getTime();
}
public static void setFoo(Object obj) {
    //Do something with `obj`
}
```

So, inline property means that the code of the getter/setter function will be inlined into the call site when accessing the property (same as regular inline functions).

```
//In Kotlin
val x = "".foo
val y = "".bar

//Generated code
val x = InlinedExtensionPropertyKt.getFoo("")
val y = Date().time
```

For the bytecode that you post in the question, sorry that I am not able explain what is happening. But you may try to take a look at the bytecode of the following code:

```
fun get() {
    val x = "".foo
    val y = "".bar
}
```

, where `"".foo` will invoke the getter function but `"".bar` will not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think the bytecode is just more than you suggest. Do you thing that is good to inline every extension property ?

Comment: @crgarridos To me, most of the time, function call overhead is not a big deal. I would consider using `inline` when I need reified type parameters. You may take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292802/what-are-the-use-cases-of-kotlin-inline-properties) for reference.

Comment: I found a use: `inline val <reified T> T.TAG : String get() = T::class.java.simpleName` :)

Comment: Yea, it is a valid and good use of the reified type parameter. To make it better, I would use `T::class.qualifiedName` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841067/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-log-tag-constant-in-kotlin) because of this [issue](https://medium.com/@elye.project/the-danger-of-using-class-getsimplename-as-tag-for-fragment-5cdf3a35bfe2).